# How to change the color of svg styled icon in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web

```
const MyIconContainer = styled(IconAlt)`
  margin-bottom: -1px;
`;
```

I'm not sure why, but changing the color of "IconAlt" has been tricky. I've tried setting it just below margin-bottom, something like

```
color: ${props => props.theme.gray.darker}
```

but this has no effect on the icon itself- I assume it's just affecting the "container".

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I just figured it out. There is an outer paragraph which contains the IconContainer, and within that is an svg property that gives me the option to fill with a certain color. So I changed that to:

```
const MyStatus = styled.p`
  margin: 0px;
  svg {
    fill: ${props => props.theme.gray.darker}; //<-- here is where I needed to set the color
  }
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
`;
```

And that changed the icon color for me.

Answer (score 0):

1-( best way ):

**create a component for all icons and export all like this and set prop color for every fill attr of your svg then use it `<Icon color="red"` />**

```
export const Icon= ({ size, color }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={size}
      height={size}
      fill={color}
      viewBox="0 -192 512 512"
    >
      <path d="M320 64c0 35.348-28.652 64-64 64s-64-28.652-64-64 28.652-64 64-64 64 28.652 64 64zm0 0M128 64c0 35.348-28.652 64-64 64S0 99.348 0 64 28.652 0 64 0s64 28.652 64 64zm0 0M512 64c0 35.348-28.652 64-64 64s-64-28.652-64-64 28.652-64 64-64 64 28.652 64 64zm0 0"></path>
    </svg>
  );
};
```

2: styled component way:

```
  const Icon = styled.svg(
      ({ color }) => ({
        fill:color,
      })
    );

      export const MyIcon = ({color}) => {

      return(
    
    <Icon
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      fill={color}
      viewBox="0 -192 512 512"
    >
      <path d="M320 64c0 35.348-28.652 64-64 64s-64-28.652-64-64 28.652-64 64-64 64 28.652 64 64zm0 0M128 64c0 35.348-28.652 64-64 64S0 99.348 0 64 28.652 0 64 0s64 28.652 64 64zm0 0M512 64c0 35.348-28.652 64-64 64s-64-28.652-64-64 28.652-64 64-64 64 28.652 64 64zm0 0"></path>
    </Icon>
    
    );
};
```